# How to apply CSS style in javascript for id generated at runtime

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my code I have a table, to which I'd like to apply this style:

```
#tableDiv tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

In the above code div's id is known (it's tableDiv). In my project div's id is generated during runtime and it's some random string. How can I apply the style in javascript code.
Let's say I generated my div's id like this:

```
mContainer = document.createElement("div");
newId = divIdGenerator();
mContainer.setAttribute("id", newId);
```

What should I do next to apply my style?

Comment: With a class instead? You can only select an element with CSS by knowing a selector. If you don't know the ID, then can you not target it's parent's children?

Comment: Do you  just want zebra striping for your table rows? ie grey for even and white for odd (for example). Then however many rows get added to the table, they will always be alternate stripes. If so this is just a simple css issue, no need for javascript. If not then you might have to supply more html, or a working example. What does `divIdGenerator();` do for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use CSS class

```js
var mContainer = document.createElement("div");

//adds class "table-div" to element
mContainer.classList.add('table-div');
```

```css
.table-div tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Why is this a runnable snippet?

Comment: Simple and great solution. I totally forgot about classes and focused on using id. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Add a CSS class that does this for you:

```
.striped-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

and then add the class to the classlist:

```
mContainer.classList.add("striped-table");
```